# how do I UPDATE specific columns in a table from CSV without replacing the entire row?

Tags: mysql

I have a set of csv files I'm importing into mysql and I made a few mistakes in sorting the data. I need to do a mass update of specific rows in a table without updating the entire table (there have been a few changes to the table and importing everything over again will revert the changes).

this is the command I've been using to import the csv files:

```
LOAD DATA LOW_PRIORITY LOCAL INFILE 'C:\\location\\of\\CSVs\\import.csv' 
REPLACE INTO TABLE `database`.`contacts` CHARACTER SET utf8 
FIELDS TERMINATED BY ',' 
OPTIONALLY ENCLOSED BY '"' 
LINES TERMINATED BY '\r\n' 
IGNORE 2 LINES 
(`id`, `deleted`, `salutation_name`, `first_name`, `last_name`, `account_id`, 
`description`, `created_at`, `modified_at`, `created_by_id`, 
`modified_by_id`, `assigned_user_id`);
```

I tried to use INSERT in place of REPLACE:

```
LOAD DATA LOW_PRIORITY LOCAL INFILE 'C:\\location\\of\\CSVs\\import.csv' 
INSERT INTO TABLE `database`.`contacts` 
CHARACTER SET utf8 
FIELDS TERMINATED BY ',' 
OPTIONALLY ENCLOSED BY '"' 
LINES TERMINATED BY '\r\n' 
IGNORE 2 LINES 
(`id`, `created_by_id`, `assigned_user_id`);
```

But it threw errors (expectedly) and didn't update a dang thing!

Basically I want to import only two of the columns, `created_by_id` and `assigned_user_id`, from the csv based on the first column, `id` but I'm not entirely sure how to do that without replacing everything in the table.

I'm pretty sure I need  `WHERE` statement in there somewhere to tell mysql what to base it's changes on, but I'm not entirely sure what/where to put in.

To be clear, I am a bit of a mysql script kiddie (this is my first database and first foray into mysql), but I was smart enough to create a db backup and copied the table to a temp table before tinkering with things.

Comment: DId you cut the CSV file down to a file with only 3 columns

Comment: Yes. I made sure to remove all columns except the three "important" ones.

Comment: make a new table copy insert the hile csv and the update the old table with the data of the new. agter that you delete then ew table

Comment: I kindof understand... so I copy the table (call it `temp_contacts`), the import the corrected csv into `temp_contacts`. thats where you lose me... I then copy the columns in question into the original `contacts` table? ok... how? what ensures the right field gets replaces respective of the row id? like I said, new rows have been added.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, handy syntax `LOAD DARA INFILE` does not support `REPLACE`, or other options such as `ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE`.

If your table was initialized from the CVS file, I would recommend just truncating the table and reloading the CSV with the proper command.

In the other hand if you can’t afford truncating the table, then another option is to load the CSV file into a temporary table, then update the target table from the temp table. Assuming that you loaded the file in temp table `tmp_contacts`, and the the primary key is `id`, your `update` statement would be:

```
update contacts c
inner join tmp_contacts t
    on t.id = c.id
set 
    c.created_by_id = t.created_by_id,
    c.assigned_user_id = t.assigned_user_id
```

If your table has many columns, it is possible to skip the columns you don’t need when loading in the temporary table. The MySQL documentation explains how to do that, using session variables.

Comment: perfect! that was what I was looking for! @nbk, I know this is what you were talking about, but like I said, I'm a script kiddie here. I needed the commands spelled out.